# QMovie is private

Tags: qt, return, private

I have this:

```
QMovie Tests::QMovieReturn() {
    QMovie ReturnMovie;
    ReturnMovie->setFileName("Test.gif");
    return ReturnMovie;
}
```

But it says: 'QMovie::QMovie(const QMovie&)' is private
within this context. (Line that sends me to the return ReturnMovie)

If iremove the return everything works fine. Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the compiler says, that copy constructor is private. It means that developers of Qt did not want you to use it. The workaround, or better to say the proper use of QMovie is to create it on the heap.

```
QMovie* ReturnMovie = new QMovie;
```

Comment: If that's the only way since i can't return, there's not another class that lets me return the Animated GIF?

Comment: @Kazuma You can perfectly return `QMovie *`.

Comment: QMovie MyFunction::TestFunction() {
    QMovie* MyMovie = new QMovie;
    return MyMovie;
}

I've done that (If you mean that). Still getting the isuse. :/

Comment: Woops! Think i got it!


QMovie *MyFunction::TestFunction() {
    QMovie *MyMovie = new QMovie;
    return MyMovie;
}

Answer (score 1):

You probably should use `new` to allocate your `QMovie` dynamically, and return a pointer, since `QMovie`s obviously don't want to be copied.